# Subjunctive mood in "I wish your day is/be ..."?

Tags: word-choice, subjunctives

> 1. I wish your day be a wonderful day.
> 2. I wish your day is a wonderful day.

Which sentence is correct? Notice that I am thinking to use it in place of "I wish you have a wonderful day" in addiction of another wish phrase.

Comment: I think *I wish your day to be a wonderful day* would be better grammatically. Then again, I would personally simply say *I wish you a wonderful day*.

Comment: I know that one I was just looking for a different way to wish someone. anyways thanks for your comment.

Comment: I agree with Damkemg, but I myself never heard  anyone say it that way.However, If you are looking for a different way to wish someone and don't want to use " I wish you a wonderful day" which is more common, you can  also say "wishing you a wonderful day!"

Comment: What is the source of your examples?

Comment: People if my example sentences don't make sense ): I understand if they don't since I was just making things up. (: you see I was just trying to birthday wish someone and I wanted to use that phrase but I didn't since it didn't make much sense to me either.

Comment: By the way, I wanted to say something like this: "I wanna wish you a happy birthday, I wish your day be a wonderful day and wish you have many more. Happy birthday Flor." I didn't post it though, because I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't think of a natural phrase using "wish" this way.

I would say:

> I **hope** you have a wonderful day.

*hope* as used here is a wish in context.

Comment: I see thanks for the answer... Well I just have one more question. Can you say "I hope tomorrow is a better day" or "I hope tomorrow to be a better day"?

Comment: "I hope tomorrow *will be* a better day."

Comment: I don't want to be negative but this video "https://youtu.be/3VO1F_XZBFQ"  shows that you are not supposed to used "will" with "hope" checked it out it's almost at the end of the video at min. 7:47

Comment: @ManuelHernandez Check this out: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page4.shtml.

Comment: @Damberng I checked out the link you supplied and I totally agree with the information provided on there, so I think the woman in the video I posted is retarded and don't know what she is doing. I hope somebody actually tells her she is doing wrong.

Comment: @snailboat, I agree with you!

Comment: @ManuelHernandez Oops, let me write that comment again without the typo:  "I hope tomorrow will be a better day" is perfectly grammatical, although the shorter alternative "I hope tomorrow is a better day" is also fine. The version with "to be" sounds formal and bookish, and I don't think people would normally say it.  By the way, I suggest avoiding the word *retarded* – people may take offense.  (Sorry for messing up the comment order by re-posting my comment, but I can't edit the old one anymore :-)

Comment: @snailboat it's ok. Moreover, I really appreciate your help and you know what I really meant to call that woman retarded even though it's ofensive I really think it fits her because she is misleading people I almost fall for it if it wasn't by you guys I would be in the wrong path.